# Jquery code is not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently learning jQuery. I am having some problems with the following code. I am trying to make my website move using some buttons, but once i click them it does not seem to work. Below is my jquery code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    //initialise Stellar.js
    $(window).stellar();
    //Cache some variables
    var links = $('.navigation').find('li');
    slide = $('.slide');
    button = $('.button');
    mywindow = $(window);
    htmlbody = $('html,body');
    //Setup waypoints plugin
    slide.waypoint(function (event, direction) {
        //cache the variable of the data-slide attribute associated with each slide
        dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');
        //If the user scrolls up change the navigation link that has the same data-slide attribute as the slide to active and
        //remove the active class from the previous navigation link
        if(direction === 'down') {
            $('.navigation li[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').addClass('active').prev().removeClass('active');
        }
        // else If the user scrolls down change the navigation link that has the same data-slide attribute as the slide to active and
        //remove the active class from the next navigation link
        else {
            $('.navigation li[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').addClass('active').next().removeClass('active');
        }
    });
    //waypoints doesnt detect the first slide when user scrolls back up to the top so we add this little bit of code, that removes the class
    //from navigation link slide 2 and adds it to navigation link slide 1.
    mywindow.scroll(function () {
        if(mywindow.scrollTop() === 0) {
            $('.navigation li[data-slide="1"]').addClass('active');
            $('.navigation li[data-slide="2"]').removeClass('active');
        }
    });
    //Create a function that will be passed a slide number and then will scroll to that slide using jquerys animate. The Jquery
    //easing plugin is also used, so we passed in the easing method of 'easeInOutQuint' which is available throught the plugin.
    function goToByScroll(dataslide) {
        htmlbody.animate({
            scrollTop: $('.slide[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').offset().top
        }, 2000, 'easeInOutQuint');
    }
    //When the user clicks on the navigation links, get the data-slide attribute value of the link and pass that variable to the goToByScroll function
    links.click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');
        goToByScroll(dataslide);
    });
    //When the user clicks on the button, get the get the data-slide attribute value of the button and pass that variable to the goToByScroll function
    button.click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');
        goToByScroll(dataslide);
    });
});
```

It would be great if anyone can help me solve my problem.

Comment: Have you added jQuery library? Is jQuery library loading? What error are you getting in browser console?

Comment: I think  you have to add `var` to your cached vars above. Not adding makes it global, so that could cause some issues.

Comment: Please provide us a jsfiddle example so we could help.

Comment: this is the whole code http://jsfiddle.net/b6FJA/

Comment: Code seems ok, have you some `errors` in `console`?

Comment: You have 2 jquery libraries attached. Remove the `1.4.1` version

Comment: @RohanKumar no i dont have any errors in the console

Answer (score 5):

Put your script before the closing tag body (`</body>`) and include Jquery library

Answer (score 0):

You may have conflictions of `jquery` try to use [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) after adding any version of `jquery` like,

```
<script>
     jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

Comment: i am sorry but i dont get it. should i add this under my html file?